# How to control button action on a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table that I populate from a start time - end time user input chosen from a calendar with values from mysql, and I post that values with ajax, on the same ajax post I send the button also like this:

```
button: "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Image</button>"
```

And I would get a table that is looking like this:

[image]

How I can control the functionality of each button?

Lets say, if I press the first one, it will console.log 13940 (value of the weight) and when I press the second one, it will console.log 13000?

Also I would like to make some more functionality like, when a certain button is pressed, make a sql query based on that added date and console log a value from database that is associated to that added date?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type=\"button\" data-id=\"13940\" class=\"getid btn btn-default\">Image</button>
```

after clicking on this button you get id

```
$('.getid').on('click', function(){
     // you can make ajax call here to get data
     console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

you can get basic idea from it.

Comment: I get undefined in the console each time I click.

Comment: console.log(this) and check what you getting

Comment: you do not added the data-id to button

Answer (score 0):

when you bind button with Html add id of the button which is unique id.

```
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\">Image</button>
```

**Edit**

```
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"yourid\">Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will give you the value.

```
$("button").click(function(){
      var ref = $(this).parent().parent().find("tr:first-child").text();
     console.log(ref);
});
```

Note: just try adding or removing parent() function for exact reference.
This code works without touching actual code